# d3.js continue condition load data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working wiht d3.js ad force layout, but i have this problem: 
TypeError: c.target is undefined , i know what this is, and how to remove that but i don't want

```
 d3.json("myfile.json", function(graph) {

   var nodeMap = {};
   graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { nodeMap[d.name] = d; });
   graph.links = graph.links.map(function(d) {
     return { 
         source: nodeMap[d.source] ,
         target: nodeMap[d.target] ,
         value: d.value
          };
  });

force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();
```

this is my code to load json data and build the graph.

```
if i put ( || 0  )in  :

                      source: nodeMap[d.source] || 0, 
                      target: nodeMap[d.target] ||0,
```

this breaks the code and don't draw links for the "d"node.
    Instead i want something like "continue statement" that jump to the next c.target  of the same "d" node.

can someone help me

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to know how to skip links for which no target is defined?

Comment: make a jsfiddle and share... this ll be helpful to help

Comment: yes. for example 
    nodes:[{name:A},{name:B}],links:[{source:A,target:B},    [source:A,target:C]]
in this case the code report error c.target undefined, but i want only A--B interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the links which reference nodes that aren't present:

```
graph.links = graph.links.filter(function(d) {
    return nodeMap[d.source] && nodeMap[d.target];
}).map(function(d) {
    return { 
      source: nodeMap[d.source] ,
      target: nodeMap[d.target]
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you Lars but this works exactly like  solution with ||0;
the result is that i have one half graph with nodes and link and the other half  without links .
i think because if the node A have 5 "target" and the first doesn't matches the other 4 are skipped . i aspect to see the others links

Comment: This code will collect all the links for which both source and target are defined. If one of them is not defined, you can't have a link.

Comment: Ok,thanks,forgive me is my first time with d3 e js. How can i find the c.target that is missing ??  in which position i have to put the console.log().

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to create nodes for the ones that are referenced in links?

Comment: Yes, i want know what is the node that is missing

Comment: Thanks, i've solved with your code and  node.append("text").text(function(d){return d.name}) .Now i know the name of the nodes that don't have links